# Where to use new HTML5 tags?

Tags: css, html, tags

I am trying to figure out where it'd be best to use the new HTML5 tags... but according to what I read, it seems like there's no real application my site. And unsure if bad or not...

For an image sharing site, such as http://imgur.com/ where would it be appropriate to use `<header> <main> <section> <article> <aside> <dialog> or <nav>`.

When would I use the main tag?
And would the top bar be a header? (It doesnt have the title of the document nor navigational links, more of a menu)

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on the tags at: http://html5doctor.com/

Comment: best html5 element: <canvas>

Answer (score 0):

Here are a list of important tags in *HTML5* that would be helpful in defining various portions of content in a webpage.

**Header**:

```
<header>
```

**Navigation**

```
<nav>
```

**Main Content**

```
<main>
```

**Surrounding Content (Extra content that is unrelated/somewhat related to your main content)**

```
<aside>
```

**Footer**

```
<footer>
```

You can use `Sjoerd Visscher's HTML Enabling Script` for previous versions of IE such as IE8:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```